# iPhone device has taken over!

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, debugging, ios-simulator

I have been developing an iPhone app for a few months now (my first app) using the 3.1.2 SDK. All of a sudden, my app started defaulting to running on the device during debug. I assumed that somehow my target settings had changed, but when I checked them, they said they were targeting the simulator, not the device. I checked all the targets configurations and they were set accordingly (debug, release, distribution). Does anybody have any clue what's going on? Right now I'm cursed to debugging solely on the device, which takes forever.

Thanks!
-Matt

Comment: Sad to say it to you but in the long run, there is nothing comparing to routinely debugging on the device. There are a million reasons for that, a few of them:

    * Your customers all run devices, not simulators
    * Debugging on your device by default, means you'll likely start up and run your app on device hundreds/thousands of times. Having run your app thousands of times without seeing any crashes, will leave you with a warm feeling that your customers won't write bad reviews about crashing because they will likely not see any crashes.